# Regex issue i am stuck with

Tags: c#, regex, lookbehind, negative-lookbehind

I have to write a regex for matching a pattern `1-6/2011`.
In this case, digits before the `/` can not be greater than `12`. 
So I have to select digits between `1-12`.

I have written a regex:

```
^[1-9][0-2]?\s*[-−—]\s*[1-9][0-2]?\s*/\s*2[01][0-9][0-9]$
```

However, here I am getting 20-6/2014 also as a match.

I tried with a negative look-behind:

```
^[1-9](?<![2-9])[0-2]?\s*[-−—]\s*[1-9](?<![2-9])[0-2]?\s*/\s*2[01][0-9][0-9]$
```

Here, single digits are not getting identified.

Comment: Use `|` more. You can match all numbers 1-12 like this: `([1-9]|1[0-2])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following update of your regex:

```
^(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\s*[-−—]\s*(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\s*/\s*\s*2[01][0-9]{2}$
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3a0%3f%5b1-9%5d%7c1%5b0-2%5d)%5cs*%5b-%e2%88%92%e2%80%94%5d%5cs*(%3f%3a0%3f%5b1-9%5d%7c1%5b0-2%5d)%5cs*%2f%5cs*%5cs*2%5b01%5d%5b0-9%5d%7b2%7d%5cr%3f%24&i=1-6%2f2011%0d%0a02-12%2f2014%0d%0a12-30%2f2014%0d%0a12-31%2f2014%0d%0a12-32%2f2014%0d%0a13-31%2f2014%0d%0a20-6%2f2014&o=m)

It will not match `12-30/2014`, `12-31/2014`, `12-32/2014`, `13-31/2014`, `20-6/2014`.

It will match `1-6/2011` and `02-12/2014`.

C#:

```
var lines = "1-6/2011\r\n02-12/2014\r\n12-30/2014\r\n12-31/2014\r\n12-32/2014\r\n13-31/2014\r\n20-6/2014";
var finds = Regex.Matches(lines, @"^(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\s*[-−—]\s*(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\s*/\s*\s*2[01][0-9]{2}\r?$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Mind that `\r?` is only necessary in case we test with Multiline mode on. You can remove it when checking separate values.

Comment: i needed for 1-12 only for both cases. written this one.                                                      ^(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\s*[-−—]\s*(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\s*/\s*\s*2[01][0-9][0-9]$

Comment: Did it solve your problem, or do you need more assistance on this?

Comment: oh sorry, din see ur last comment, yup my problem got resolved. i tried in expresso and checked on debugex

Answer (score 1):

> So i have to select digits between 1-12

For that you can use regex

```
(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])
```

See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fJ6cR4/23

Comment: there seems to be problem with this regex, its giving me timeout when i am writting the full regex for the complete match ie. 1-6/2011

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?:[1-9]|1[0-2])\s*-\s*(?:[1-9]|1[0-2])\s*/\s*2[01]\d{2}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uU9mG4/1)

Comment: i am getting time out.

Comment: checked with your site link. when i added few more types of hyphens its giving time out, cause regex is taking more than 2 sec to execute. i tried with expresso, and its fine.

Comment: It is difficult to imagine how this regex is 2 sec to execute since this is pretty basic and simple regex. If you provide me some examples to reproduce this slowness then I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks anubhava, i tried in expresso tool and debuggex . its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest regex to match with 1-12 is `(1[0-2]?)|[2-9]`.

It matches with `13` cause `1[0-2]?` matches with `1`, but it doesn't matter in full regex `(1[0-2]?)|[2-9]\/\d\d\d\d`.